# How to create a fixed token and store the state information on the ledger in corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am new to corda token sdk. I want to create a cordapp for creating and selling tickets and are non-fungible. How do I store the ticketToken on the ledger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the ticket is not replaceable by others of the same type (e.g. concert ticket) you would need a `NonFungibleToken`. To build a very basic one you would need to do the following steps:

- create a state `YourState` that extends `TokenType` (or implements `ContractState`, if you need to have a contract associated with the state that can be verified with the transaction)
- create a `var issuedTokenType = IssuedTokenType(ourIdentity(), YourState)`. An `IssueTokenType` associates a `TokenType` with an `Issuer` party
- create a `var nft = new NonFungibleToken(issuedTokenType, holder, UUID)` this creates a Non-Fungible Token issued by Issuer with holder (a Party) as a receiver
- issue the token `subFlow(new IssueTokens(listOf(nft)))`

There are many other ways, depending on what you need and how rich your State needs to be (it can be [QueryableState](https://api.corda.net/api/corda-os/4.8/html/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.schemas/-queryable-state/index.html), [SchedulableState](https://api.corda.net/api/corda-os/4.8/html/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.contracts/-schedulable-state/index.html) etc), and the token-sdk provides many helpers to help you create, issue and redeem tokens. All of them have their pros and cons, it depends on what you need to achieve.

I suggest you go through the sources here below to learn how to use the token-sdk:

- [this cordapp example](https://github1s.com/sbir3japan/cordapp-coupon) where there is basically what you need. Check out the [CouponTokenType](https://github1s.com/sbir3japan/cordapp-coupon/blob/HEAD/contracts/src/main/java/jp/co/sbir3japan/states/CouponTokenType.java) that is used to issue NonFungibleTokens in [IssueCoupon flow](https://github1s.com/sbir3japan/cordapp-coupon/blob/HEAD/workflows/src/main/java/jp/co/sbir3japan/flows/IssueCoupon.java)
- the [official tutorial](https://training.corda.net/libraries/tokens-sdk/), where you will learn how to use token sdk specifically
- the [token-sdk repo on github](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/), where there is additional documentation with [various standard examples](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/docs/IWantTo.md) and [the architectural design](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/design/design.md#the-foundational-state-types) of the type of tokens available in token-sdk
- the samples dedicated to token-sdk available for both [Java](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Tokens) and [Kotlin](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Tokens). All of them create and issue tokens.

With the above sources you will definitely be able to find everything you need to create and issue the type of token you need.

Comment: In all the samples, I see only evolvabletokens getting created, but in my case I need a fixed one, that never evolves. How do I achieve that.

Comment: Hi @laplace , did you get the solution, like fixed one?